# Fedex Rate API Request

Tags: php, api, fedex

I need to create a simple webpage that gets rate quotes from **FedEx**. Only thing is, I've never messed with an *API* before.

The XML is easy, but how do I send that XML to FedEx and view the response? API Request... Yes I know, but what is the code for an API request to FedEx? I just need some guidance. I know PHP to an extent - but, I'm no expert.

I understand that I need to send an API request but I need a simple working example using PHP. I want to be able to input my account information and then have a simple working rate quote.

I don't care if it only returns the simplest data. I just need to have something to get me started.

It seems as if FedEx only goes so far in providing information for doing this with PHP.

Comment: Here is tutorial from FedEx site on how to create the codes. Updated Link: Check This Link : https://github.com/JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/tree/master/examples From this [page](https://www.fedex.com/login/web/jsp/logon.jsp?TYPE=33554432&REALMOID=06-00047ebe-e235-1f50-a0ab-0e650affb0c4&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-OpHyFGH8DMj4DjL7QkUcaKvAJVFKOiFfZ6KRIwgidFMO8Dsr%2bC2PSJIr8eaAQQFW&TARGET=-SM-HTTPS://www.fedex.com/login/redirect?TARGET=HTTPS-:-/-/www.fedex.com-/wpor-/web-/jsp-/drclinks.jsp-?links-=wss-/getstarted.html), scroll to the bottom and select the "Download code i

Comment: I've already watched this. Where is the "sample code" she is talking about? I see nothing of the sort.

Comment: See this link http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1276-PHP-Interface-to-FedEx-Ship-Manager.html

Comment: when trying to test `ship` im getting errors `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Element 'Major' has fixed value '12' (value '10' is not allowed)`

Comment: That would be because your wsdl (version 12) version doesnt match the version hardwired into that example code (version 10). In ship.php $version->setMajor(10) would need to be repalced with $version->setMajor(12)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fedex offers acceleration packages in www.fedex.com/us/developer/ , you will find information about different types of calls to their webservices. as an example if you want to request a rate from fedex you will need to do something like this:

```
<?php

require_once('../../library/fedex-common.php5');

$newline = "<br />";
//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "../../wsdl/RateService_v13.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'UserCredential' =>array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
); 
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request v13 using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
    'Major' => '13', 
    'Intermediate' => '0', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['TotalInsuredValue']=array('Ammount'=>100,'Currency'=>'USD');
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = addShipper();
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'ACCOUNT'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'LIST'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();
try 
{
    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint'))
    {
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
    }

    $response = $client ->getRates($request);

    if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR')
    {   
        $rateReply = $response -> RateReplyDetails;
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>Service Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Delivery Date</td></tr><tr>';
        $serviceType = '<td>'.$rateReply -> ServiceType . '</td>';
        $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount,2,".",",") . '</td>';
        if(array_key_exists('DeliveryTimestamp',$rateReply)){
            $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->DeliveryTimestamp . '</td>';
        }else if(array_key_exists('TransitTime',$rateReply)){
            $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->TransitTime . '</td>';
        }else {
            $deliveryDate='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        echo $serviceType . $amount. $deliveryDate;
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

        printSuccess($client, $response);
    }
    else
    {
        printError($client, $response);
    } 

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   printFault($exception, $client);        
}

function addShipper(){
    $shipper = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '9012638716'),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Collierville',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
            'PostalCode' => '38017',
            'CountryCode' => 'US')
    );
    return $shipper;
}
function addRecipient(){
    $recipient = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Recipient Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '9012637906'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Richmond',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'BC',
            'PostalCode' => 'V7C4V4',
            'CountryCode' => 'CA',
            'Residential' => false)
    );
    return $recipient;                                      
}
function addShippingChargesPayment(){
    $shippingChargesPayment = array(
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
        'Payor' => array(
            'ResponsibleParty' => array(
            'AccountNumber' => getProperty('billaccount'),
            'CountryCode' => 'US')
        )
    );
    return $shippingChargesPayment;
}
function addLabelSpecification(){
    $labelSpecification = array(
        'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D', // valid values COMMON2D, LABEL_DATA_ONLY
        'ImageType' => 'PDF',  // valid values DPL, EPL2, PDF, ZPLII and PNG
        'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_7X4.75');
    return $labelSpecification;
}
function addSpecialServices(){
    $specialServices = array(
        'SpecialServiceTypes' => array('COD'),
        'CodDetail' => array(
            'CodCollectionAmount' => array('Currency' => 'USD', 'Amount' => 150),
            'CollectionType' => 'ANY')// ANY, GUARANTEED_FUNDS
    );
    return $specialServices; 
}
function addPackageLineItem1(){
    $packageLineItem = array(
        'SequenceNumber'=>1,
        'GroupPackageCount'=>1,
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 50.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        ),
        'Dimensions' => array(
            'Length' => 108,
            'Width' => 5,
            'Height' => 5,
            'Units' => 'IN'
        )
    );
    return $packageLineItem;
}

?>
```

so go to fedex.com, download wsdl or xml with library and more. run this code and you will receive a quote. important to say that you need an account to access that area, where you will receive a test meter-account to try, and then move to production.. hope it helps.

Comment: I have an account and I have that code. Just don't know where to download those files. I can't find them anywhere.

Comment: if you are logged into the platform press this link https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/getstarted.html

Comment: Got it. I must be a dummy to have that elude me.

Thanks

Comment: great. please mark the question as solved to close the question. brgds!